# Is there a good analogy between spectral representation of a signal and graph theory?

Tags: graphs, fourier-transform, time-series-analysis, signal-processing

I am working on some time series problems where the Fourier representation of the signal in the frequency domain is also important. I am wondering if there is any connection between time series signals consisting of sinusoidal/inherently periodic functions (functions that can be cleanly represented by a sum of sinusoids) and graph theory.

Thanks,
Josiah

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  I'm not sure that this question fits our criteria for questions.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Any community votes?

Comment: Please do some work, say, pick your favorite (truncated) Fourier series and we can try to make connections to graph theory.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a connection to graph theory? Why do you *want* there to be a connection to graph theory? I feel that we are missing some background.